# parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)

Tags: loops, haskell

I have to do a problem which receive a int n and calculate the sum of n integers that are put it in the IO.

This is the code

```
ej13 :: Integer -> IO ()
ej13 n = do if n==0
               then return 0
               else do m <- getLine
                       let eme = read m :: Int
                       return (n+m)
```

What's the problem on that code?
Thanks.

Comment: This won't compile even if you fix the indentation since you're trying to add a string `m` to an integer `n`. You probably meant to use `eme` instead. Your return type should be `IO Integer`, and you also need to make a recursive call to get the sum of the remaining values.

Answer (score 3):

Your code mixes tabs and spaces; stop doing that and just change them all <sub><sup>to tabs</sup></sub>.

Comment: Or change them all to spaces.  I'm not looking to start that argument all over again, tabs are just fine, but I would recommend spaces since GHC interprets tabs as 8 spaces, and while it may look correct when you have your tabs set to 2 or 4 spaces, [it can still generate a parse error](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/Tabs).

Comment: @bheklilr: Yeah, spaces are best for this type of use of layout; I prefer it when the `do` is on another line, though, hence the comment. Tabs for alignment, ironically, aren’t pretty =D